# AppLab "readRecords()" is broken

Tags: javascript, code.org, app-lab

I'm year 10 and my final project for APCS is to make a game/app and turn in the code, a video of it running, and a written response. My problem is that the entire class was taught using Code.org's AppLab and the readRecords() function is seemingly broken , I think its readRecords() because the concept version of the game doesn't use readRecords and works fine, but the current version does and nearly half of the buttons in the game don't work most of the time. Including the buttons to log in, sign up, etc.Meaning I can't even get past the welcome screen. My code isn't the issue and this is due in a few hours. s u g g e s t i o n s   p l e a s e.

Answer (score 1):

[applab docs for `readRecords`](https://code.org/applab/docs/readRecords)

it looks like `readRecords` should probably still be supported

you should use your browser's javascript console/debugger to find your application's point of failure

here's some ideas for where that point of failure might be:

1. in your code which is using `readRecords` incorrectly

   - you have to find the bug and fix it yourself
2. in applab's `readRecords` code itself (less likely)

   - you have to submit a bug report to applab
   - find a workaround until you can implement a potential fix from applab

Answer (score 0):

Because you are saying that your buttons do not work "most of the time", and the readRecords() command is asynchronous, I suspect you have a timing issue of some kind. To help determine if the problem is with the readRecords() command or with how you're using it in your project, you could put the share link to your project here, or in a message to code.org support.

Comment: No, it can't be that because no matter how long I wait the buttons do not work. And this changes if I open the game up in a private window, refresh the page, etc.

Comment: It is still possible that you have a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition), which would mean that your program might work correctly sometimes and incorrectly other times, regardless of how long you wait. If you'd like a more conclusive answer but don't want to share your project, you could include just the section of code related to readRecords() which you believe is working incorrectly.